# InDesign scripting error "ReferenceError: Object is invalid"

Tags: javascript, templates, curl, autohotkey, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to bring back to life and older script I had used that worked in the past.  The script would download comics (that we have the rights to) using autohotkey and curl...  Then in InDesign we would run the following from the javascript Scripts panel:

```
#targetengine "session"
var date, month, year, myDocument;
var curDate = new Date();
var myTemplatePath = "/c/Comic/ComicImport.indd";
var myComicsPath = "/c/Comic/Comics/";
var myTemplate = new File(myTemplatePath);



if (myTemplate.exists) {
    try {
        myDocument = app.open(myTemplate);
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Could not open template, exiting\n" + e);
        exit();
    }
    var win = showDialog();
} else {
    alert("Could not locate template at:\n" + myTemplatePath + "\nexiting");
}



function showDialog() {
    var win = new Window('palette');
    with(win){
        win.Pnl = add('panel', undefined, 'Date / Month / Year');
        win.Pnl.orientation = 'row';
        with(win.Pnl) {
            win.Pnl.day = add('edittext');
            win.Pnl.day.text = curDate.getDate();
            win.Pnl.day.preferredSize = [30,20];

            win.Pnl.month = add('edittext');
            win.Pnl.month.text = curDate.getMonth() + 1;
            win.Pnl.month.preferredSize = [30,20];

            win.Pnl.year = add('edittext');
            win.Pnl.year.text = curDate.getFullYear();
            win.Pnl.year.preferredSize = [50,20];
        }
        win.btnOk = add('button', undefined, 'Import Comic');
        win.btnOk.onClick = setDate;
    };
    win.center();
    win.show();
    return win;
}
function setDate() {
    date = win.Pnl.day.text;
    month = win.Pnl.month.text;
    year = win.Pnl.year.text;
    // OK we close the window and do the import
    //win.close();
    importComics();
}



function importComics() {
    try {
        //set comic1 to "macintosh Hd:users:marshall:documents:comics:" &      DYear & Dmonth & Dday & "pzjud-a.tif"
        var comics = new Array();
        // REPLACE with own filepaths, could be
        //comics.push(new File("/c/comics/" + year + month + date + "pzjud-    a.tif"));
        comics.push(new File(myComicsPath + "comic1-" + year + "-" + month +  "-" + date + ".tif"));
        comics.push(new File(myComicsPath + "comic2-" + year + "-" + month +  "-" + date + ".tif"));
        comics.push(new File(myComicsPath + "comic3-" + year + "-" + month + "-" + date + ".tif"));
        comics.push(new File(myComicsPath + "comic4-" + year + "-" + month +  "-" + date + ".tif"));
        comics.push(new File(myComicsPath + "comic5-" + year + "-" + month +  "-" + date + ".tif"));
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Error assigning images for import, stopping script\n" + e);
        exit();
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= comics.length; i++) {
        // Script label of the rectangles/pageitems to place the graphics     into
        var myRect  = myDocument.pageItems.item("comic" + i);
        try {
        myRect.place(comics[i-1]);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
        myRect.fit(FitOptions.CONTENT_TO_FRAME);
    }
}
```

However as soon as I hit the Import Comic button, I get the "ReferenceError: Object is invalid" error.  My directory structures look ok to me.  Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Debugging with  ExtendScript Toolkit could help you to identify the problem. Also, post your target version.

Comment: Has your actual issue anything to do with AHK?

Comment: Is it possible that the script was written for an older version of InDesign than you are currently using? Try [InDesignSecrets: Using Old Scripts in CS3](http://indesignsecrets.com/using-old-scripts-in-cs3.php) (never mind that low version number in the title, that particular function also works in newer versions).

Answer (score 0):

Watch this line:

```
var myRect  = myDocument.pageItems.item("comic" + i);
```

In newest ID version it is no longer calling "item.label" but "item.name"
(the one shown in Layer Panel)

If inside your doc target rectangles have "label == comic + i" you have to repeat/move this values as rectangle's name as well.

Otherwise - your code needs to create a loop through all pageItems and check particular item.label before placing image.